# Bug in popup of add comment

Tags: bug, comments, user-interface

[image]

After clicking add comment, an error about having insufficient rep is shown, but it is not hidden after opening any other field.

Comment: Please add the OS and Browser details, not reproduced in Windows 10, Chrome and Firefox. Or link the question where you are seeing this issue.

Comment: No repro, the popup should not float, it's only near the "add comment" link.

Comment: Is that a snippet that has been expanded *after* the error popup was shown? (so the popup itself is static and hasn't moved, but everything has)

Comment: yes the snippet was opened after the error popup was shown

Comment: windows 8.1 chrome

Comment: Ok yeh I can repro that. It's because the popup is positioned absolutely relative to the page, not the comment field or anything else so if the page content moves it ends up in the wrong place (I would assume it is the same in all browsers)